# Reading Arabic PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, arabic-support

How can I read a PDF file written in Arabic using C# version 7.1?

I have tried this function:

```
private string GetTextFromPDF(String path)
{
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
        }
    }
    return text.ToString();
}
```

But it only works with English characters, any help?

Comment: forgive my ignorance, where does PdfReader come from?

Comment: from iTextSharp library

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I tried your code on [this](https://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/docs/qa-201405-arabic.pdf) PDF and it works...

Comment: Francesco B. it did for me too but in reverse order of charachters